# JavaScript: Color random connected lines

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have js amateur painter and want to work that way:
- click on position (x1, y1)
- click on position (x2, y2)
- click on position (x3, y3)

Then I have button connect and program connect last point with first one and i get some content which I can fill it with color.

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50,50);
ctx.lineTo(100,100);
ctx.lineTo(70, 150);
ctx.lineTo(50, 50);
ctx.fillStyle = "000";
ctx.fill();
```

That works great but i want to work it my way with button which connect lines when i want:

```
x = event.pageX - $("#myCanvas").offset().left;
y = event.pageY - $("#myCanvas").offset().top;
if (n == 0) {
    a = x;
    b = y;
    zx = x;
    zy = y;
}
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(a,b);
if(n != 0)
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);
ctx.stroke();
a = x;
b = y;
n = 1;
```

Down I have function for closing lines (connect first and last to get connected lines).

```
 jQuery('#connect').click(function () {
    if ((this.id == 'connect') && (
        //ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(a, b);
        ctx.lineTo(zx, zy);
        //ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = bpolnila.toString();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }
});
```

What's wrong here I tried a lot but my connected lines just don't want to fill with color.

Comment: You are missing a `'`

Comment: I once programmed something like this: http://www.kolchose.org/simon/ajaximagemapcreator/

Comment: @Johan Yes thx that was mistake when i translating to eng.

Comment: @Powtac: yes that's exactly what i need where could i see code?

Comment: So you want a line to connect the position of each click and then one from the last click back to the first? Do you want to limit it to just 3 clicks or any number of clicks?

Comment: Any number, so i can click finish when i want and script connect last with first point and fill inside.

Answer (score 0):

I once created a project for creating HTML image maps online in your browser. I also used canvas and mouse clicks to draw lines on the image: The project: http://www.kolchose.org/simon/ajaximagemapcreator/

The source code is available at http://code.google.com/p/imagemap/

Comment: Thx i've checked your code and i am using very similar (withour fill polygon) but don't see any mistake.